# How to set time to live for messages in _error queue with MassTransit?

Tags: c#, masstransit

Is it possible to set a time to live for messages in the _error queue? Or even skip this mechanism of sending the messages to the error queue as a fault is already consumed?
I am using a consumer and a fault consumer to handle errors. I no longer need the messages in the error queue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you can create a filter to discard the error and then configure the error pipeline to use it.

First, create the filter:

```
    class DiscardExceptionFilter :
        IFilter<ExceptionReceiveContext>
    {
        public async Task Send(ExceptionReceiveContext context, IPipe<ExceptionReceiveContext> next)
        {
            await context.NotifyFaulted(context.Exception).ConfigureAwait(false);

            // not calling next.Send(), to end the pipe here.
        }

        public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
        {
            context.CreateScope("no-move-error");
        }
    }
```

Once created, on the receive endpoint, configure the error pipeline to use the filter.

```
configurator.ConfigureError(x => x.UseFilter(new DiscardExceptionFilter()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I doing something wrong here? Irrespective of the exception type, nothing goes into _error queue. However, if I remove the filter altogether, as expected, all messages end up in error queue.

The same happens even if I try the `x.UseContextFilter()`.

```
e.ConfigureError(x =>
                        {
                            x.UseFilter(new ExceptionLoggerAndFilter());
                            //x.UseContextFilter(ec =>
                            //{
                            //    return Task.FromResult(!(ec.Exception is SqlException));
                            //});
                            
                        });

#-----------------------------------------

public class ExceptionLoggerAndFilter : IFilter<ExceptionReceiveContext>
    {
        public async Task Send(ExceptionReceiveContext context, IPipe<ExceptionReceiveContext> next)
        {
            if (!(context.Exception is SqlException))
            {
                await context.NotifyFaulted(context.Exception).ConfigureAwait(false);
                return;
            }

            await next.Send(context);
        }

        public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
        {
            context.CreateScope("no-move-error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30187003)

Comment: sorry, this is my first post, so didnt understand how to go about it, or how it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Or even skip this mechanism of sending the messages to the error queue as a fault is already consumed

you can [discard them](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/exceptions):

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("input-queue", ec =>
{
    ec.DiscardFaultedMessages();
});
```